# Handle error message when extraction is failed in Neoload

Tags: performance

In a userpath, I have 5 requests.
Login >> GetProfile >> GetRecentOrder >> GetOrderAmount >> Logout.
In Login, username credentials are passed through variables. Recent orderID is been extracted from the Getprofile response and passed to the GetRecentOrder request.

I want to handle the error message, in the scenario "if the user doesn't have any orders, then orderID extraction NOTFOUND". I want an output log message stating that "this username (should be replaced with username from variable list) doesn't have any recent orders" which will be helpful during the test executions with multiples users.

How to handle this in Neoload and where can I see the log message.

Tried writing this in Javascript under GetRecentOrder request. But don't see any log message even when the orderId is NOTFOUND.

```
var orderID = context.variableManager.getValue("orderID");
var username = context.variableManager.getValue("username");


if (orderID === null || orderID === 0) {
    logger.error("User '" + username + "' doesn't have any recent orders.");
} else {
    logger.info("Order ID: " + orderID);
}
```